# Functional form for pseudopotential

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

I have found [this resource](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FWBele4Ui4EC&pg=PT92&lpg=PT92&dq=pseudopotentials%20why%20subtract%20off%20Hartree&source=bl&ots=yTSb53tg1I&sig=ACfU3U0JvAIa56LhgfBtpfVlkqI2A6TdUA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ2KTLtovmAhVHSBUIHeZ3BGQQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=pseudopotentials%20why%20subtract%20off%20Hartree&f=false) quite good for a brief summary of pseudopotentials, of which I am trying to learn more about.

The author shows that, once a functional form for the pseudo-wavefunctions has been found, the 'screened' pseudopotential is given by:

$$ V^{ion}_l = \epsilon_l - V_H^{valence} - V_{XC}^{valence} -\frac{l(l+1)}{2r^2} + \frac{1}{2\psi_l^{PS}} + \frac{1}{2\psi_l^{PS}} \frac{d^2}{dr^2} \psi_l^{PS} $$

For $r<r_c$ (cutoff radius), where $\psi_l^{PS}$ is the pseudo-wavefunction, $V_H$ is the Hartree potential and $V_{XC}$ is the exchange-correlation potential. This expression is just the screened potential (from inverting the Schrodinger equation), with the $V_H$ and $V_{XC}$ contributions of the valence electrons subtracted off. For $r>r_c$, the potential is just the all-electron potential.

The author then states: "Based on these atomic pseudopotentials, the pseudopotential for the entire system takes the form:"

$$ V_{psp} = \sum_{l=0}^{l_{max}} \sum_{m=-l}^{m=l} Y_{lm}(\hat{\textbf{r}})  \ V^{ion}_l(|\textbf{r}|) \  \delta\big(|\textbf{r}| - |\textbf{r}'|\big) \  Y^*_{lm}(\hat{\textbf{r}}')$$

I would like to know where this expression has come from.

Comment: 7 months is long to not get an answer, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.